# Reading JSON string in C#

Tags: c#, json, .net

I have data in JSON file format like

```
{
   "default":{
    "name":"username",
    "school":"school_name"
    },
    
    "type1":{
    "name":"studentname",
    "school":"schoolName"
    },
    
    "type2":{
    "name":"user_name",
    "school":"schooltitle"
    }
}
```

I am reading data using

```
Dictionary<string,string> values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject< Dictionary<string,string> >( json )
```

where json is a text from json file. I want to access specific code block like if student is of type 1 then check if that type exist and access that block otherwise access default block. How to do it? I want inner block values as key value pair

Comment: Try Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,string>>values=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,string>>>(json)

Comment: That's not valid JSON. And there's a typo on top : "d**a**fault"

Comment: I would recommend you to study from this [Mozilla write-up](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) about proper structure of JSON as yours seems to be malformed. You'll then able to deserialize it easily once you got it setup properly. =)

Comment: Why `Dictionary<string,string>`? I would use `Dictionary<string,(string name, string school)>` or create a class to hold `Name` and `School` properties

Comment: Please take note that there are no such things as a JSON **object**. They are a textual representation of JS objects, and therefore are **string**s

Comment: We should make a distinction here: First, you need to fix that JSON. Because you can have your deserialization correct all you want - as long as the json is invalid, it won't work. So as soon, as that's fixed we can have a look at what you need to do in code.

Comment: Why dont you use JObject class by using the newtonsoft.json.linq library. I found this to be the best to handle json object on serverside. Install the nuget package

Comment: @RomanRyzhiy Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,string>>values=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,string>>>(json)   I tried this but unable to access "type1" from it...could you please tell me how to access it?

Comment: @A.A. did you read and understand this article? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: `dictionaryName["Keyname"]` is one of the way to access value in a dictionary. Note that with this data structure there can only be one students of type 1.

Answer (score 1):

If we fix the Json with the missing `,`  you should be able to `Deserialize` it to
`Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>`:

```
var innerData = new Dictionary<string, string>{
    {"name", "username"}, 
    {"school", "school_name"}
};
var data = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>{
    {"default", innerData}, 
    {"type1", innerData}, 
    {"type2", innerData}, 
};      

string inputJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
```

Note that the generated Json match yours:

```
{
 "default":{"name":"username", "school":"school_name"}
 , "type1":{"name":"username", "school":"school_name"}
 , "type2":{"name":"username", "school":"school_name"}
}
```

And the deseralization:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject< Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> >(inputJson);

var type1Element = result["type1"];
foreach(var keyValue in type1Element){
    Console.WriteLine("{keyValue.Key} => {keyValue.Value}");

}
```

[online Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gb5h8d).

Answer (score 0):

I hope the below code will work. (Though, I haven't tested it)

```
JObject jsonObject = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(your_json);
string selectedBlock;
string to_check = "type1"; // I have hardcoded this for example

try
{ 
if((string)jsonObject.SelectToken(to_check)!=null)
selectedBlock = (string)jsonObject.SelectToken(to_check);
else
selectedBlock = (string)jsonObject.SelectToken("default");
}
catch (Exception e)
{
throw e;
}
```

Comment: No, it won't. Unrelated to if the code actually has the potential to work, it cannot. The json is invalid. So any reasonable answer must also include a fix to the input data.

Comment: I have updated the json in question also. I have tried but it is saying can convert object to string at if((string)jsonObject.SelectToken(to_check)!=null)